# How do I find errors in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to find the smallest of the biggest sum of each column of every possible permutations of a given 2D array NxN, where the values in each row can shift towards the left. For example, the array

```
4 6 
3 7
```

would have 4 possibles permutations:

```
4 6   6 4   4 6    6 4
3 7   3 7   7 3    7 3
```

The biggest sum of each permutation is respectively, 13, 11, 11, 13. Thus the smallest of the biggest sums is 11. I have written a recursive function that should work, but for some reason, it only works for arrays that are smaller than 6x6... I'm new at programming, and just recently learned about recursion, any help or counsel on how to think recursively and to debug code would be greatly appreciated...

For the array 4x4

```
7410 1371 2665 3195
4775 4130 6499 3414
300 2092 4009 7638
5351 210 7225 7207
```

The answer is 18349, and my code gives me the correct answer.

However, for the array 6x6

```
5219 842 7793 2098 5109 2621
1372 3253 3804 5652 810 1620
4894 6792 1784 4335 4772 6656
3203 1070 4716 5335 1157 6855
5529 2767 2205 408 7516 7454
375 7036 2597 5288 937 2893
```

The answer should be 23733, but I've got 24176. How is this possible?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_N 1000

int n, matrix[MAX_N][MAX_N], shift[MAX_N] = {0}, minSum = 100000000;

void possibTree(int position){
    
    //Base case
    if(position == n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Temporary array to store the values in the row that just shifted towards the left
            int temp[MAX_N] = {0};
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if(j - shift[i] < 0)
                    temp[n+(j-shift[i])] = matrix[i][j];
                else
                    temp[j-shift[i]] = matrix[i][j];
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                matrix[i][k] = temp[k];
        }
        
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                temp += matrix[j][i];
            }
            if(temp > max)
                max = temp;
        }
        if(minSum > max)
            minSum = max;
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        shift[position] = i;
        possibTree(position+1);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    while(cin >> n){
        memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));
        memset(shift, 0, sizeof(shift));
        if(n == -1) // The user enters "-1" to end the loop and terminate the program.
            return 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cin >> matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        possibTree(0);
        cout << minSum << endl;
        minSum = 100000000;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***How do I find errors in a recursive function?*** The same way you do for any other function. Use your debugger to step through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables at each step. Don't just run your code in the debugger actively use the debugger to investigate.

Comment: I see, I'm using Xcode, and I'm still a bit confused how to use it to see what's going on in the "function tree" after the functions calls itself, and before the base case ends the loop...

Comment: and also, do you have any idea why my code only works for arrays that are smaller than 6x6? I've tested it and it works fine for everything that is smaller than 6x6. I have no idea why it doesn't work

Comment: `j-shift[i]` in `temp[j-shift[i]] = matrix[i][j];` not sure if this can be less than 0.

Comment: If the position of the value is at 0, and we move it 1 position towards the left, then it would be -1

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: So, there is one point which seems odd: For each shift, you go through the whole matrix and overwrite the original matrix with the shifted values. You never put them back, yet still increase the shift for the next iteration? It seems to me that with your approach, you would need to "reset" the matrix after each iteration. Or, probably better, always shift it by 1 at a time.

Comment: Yes! It worked, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I reset the matrix to its original state at the end of each base case

Comment: thank you @drescherjm too! I'll check how to use the debugger more efficiently

Comment: You may want to answer your own question with adding the updated code and a brief explanation of the change.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok! I just posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok I believe I understand my mistake, I have to reset the matrix to its original state at the end of each base case, when the matrices are small, the code is still capable of finding all the possible biggest sums, but when the matrices got bigger, some of the possibilities weren't generated. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_N 1000

int n, matrix[MAX_N][MAX_N], OrigMatrix[MAX_N][MAX_N], shift[MAX_N] = {0}, minSum = 100000000;

void possibTree(int position){
    
    //Base case
    if(position == n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Temporary array to store the values in the row that just shifted towards the left
            int temp[MAX_N] = {0};
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if(j - shift[i] < 0)
                    temp[n+(j-shift[i])] = matrix[i][j];
                else
                    temp[j-shift[i]] = matrix[i][j];
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                matrix[i][k] = temp[k];
        }
        
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                temp += matrix[j][i];
            }
            if(temp > max)
                max = temp;
        }
        if(minSum > max)
            minSum = max;
        //EDITS
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = OrigMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        shift[position] = i;
        possibTree(position+1);
    }
    
    return;
}

int main() {
    while(cin >> n){
        memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));
        memset(shift, 0, sizeof(shift));
        if(n == -1) // The user enters "-1" to end the loop and terminate the program.
            return 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cin >> matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        //EDITS
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                OrigMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        possibTree(0);
        
        cout << minSum << endl;
        minSum = 100000000;
    }
    return 0;
}
```